# Adding SSL to server side rendered application

Tags: reactjs, ssl, single-page-application

I'm converting my currently S3 hosted react application to a server side rendered react application. I understand that I should add HTTPS to this for security, but I'm a little confused as to what I should do.

Currently, I have an EC2 instance that is hosting my API (which is a microservice). This server has a private key and a certificate.

Now my understanding with SSR is this -

1. I have a node server that is serving certain routes with server side rendered html.
2. This node server is associated with my domain.
3. When a user hits my domain, they are going to be hitting html that is served by this server.
4. This server is then going to make API calls to my api server.

I want 3 and 4 to be encrypted.

My API server has a private key that is a wildcard key with a certificate.

Can I use this same private key and certificate with my server that is rendering my html?

Otherwise, do I generate a new private key/certificate pair for the server rendering the html? So in this case, there are two SSL handshakes - one between user and html rendering server, and one between the html rendering server and the api server.

The latter seems unnecessary. What is the correct choice?

Answer (score 1):

When you make your website (UI) served on https, you have to make requests to your api on https also, i.e. you cannot have for eg. https://HelloFoo.com which is fetching data from non https api.

You will have to get a domain from some vendor, and using the domain name you will get a certificate thats supports the domain (letsencrypt is free service), you will have to upload the certificate (public key, private key and certificate chain files) to the network load balancer to serve requests.

In your network load balancer, you should be able create routes for default (/*) to direct to your html service and (/api/*) to your api service.

You are allowed to use same certificate not just on different services on one domain, you could use them on multiple domains as well ( you need register with certificate provider as such)